# Jasmine: Testing promises. Is there something like $provide.value() for Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, jasmine, ionic2

I'm trying to test a promise in Angular2, something like this:

```
this.fooService.getData().then(data => this.fooData = data);
```

[This article](http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Testing_Promises_with_Jasmine_Provide_Spy/) shows how to test promises for Angular 1. 
I know I can do this:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
  provide(FooService, {useClass: fooService})
]);
```

But I'm hoping  `$provide.value` is some other functionality I can use because I keep getting this error `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.fooService.getData().then')`
It doesn't like the `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fakeAsync and flushMicrotasks or tick to pass the time in angular/core/testing.
One of my test might look something like

```
it('should set the active module', <any>fakeAsync(() => {
   let expected = { id: 'id1' };
   jasmine.createSpyObj<FooService>('FooService'['getData']);
   spyService.fooService.and.callFake(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(expected);
   });
   let component = new FooComponent(fooService);
   component.getData();
   flushMicrotasks();
   expect(component.fooData).toEqual(expected);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try this